# Wordpress Woocommerce - Divi - Add to cart Button - Problem

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, divi

I was adding a code to the function.php file for adding a "add to cart"-button on the woocommerce divi product page in wordpress. this worked well. but now if I´m pressing the button I get a spinning boat emoji and when it´s finished there is a surfer emoji. this is really strange as I dont know where it comes from. maybe smbdy can help me. on desktop everything works fine but on mobile (tried on iOS) I get these emojis.

Thanks in advance and best regards from beijing,
michael

[while putting smthg in the basket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u23f.jpg)
[when finished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Eol.jpg)

code I used:

```
// Add "Add to Cart" buttons in Divi shop pages
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
```

---